# Generate SSRS Report from a C# object

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report

I need to combine results from 3 seperate databases and combine them into one dataset then push it up to SSRS to generate a report. Createing the dataset is complete but now I don't know how to push that result up and generate a report. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the report creation wizard *(add-->new item-->report wizard)*, it asks what dataset you want to use.  Just select the one you want and hit next.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170246%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for SSRS tutorials.